# How to manage go-rest servers based on OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: go, openapi

My current API is written in Perl using Mojolicious and its OpenAPI plugin.

The advantage of this plugin, as I see it, is, that it reads an OpenAPI spec and generates all the routes and validations upon server startup. The linkage of the endpoints to the actual methods is done by defining them in the OpenAPI spec as "x-mojo-to" properties.

So I just have to write the methods once and when my spec is enhanced or extended, I do not lose the work I did, but simply need to write the new methods.

How can I achieve this in go?

I could only find modules which generate boilerplate code which I have to fill with my methods.

But what happens when I have to extend or enhance the API spec? The boilerplate will be regenerated and I will have to redo the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a tool like https://github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen, you don't edit the generated files. So when you add a route to the openapi spec and regenerate, you "only" need to implement the one new method that was added to the server interface.